# Set position of <div> at runtime

Tags: javascript, html, css

On mouseover I want to move the "imgbox" to a specific absolute position (which might move it on top of the "i" image).

The second image ("newimg") loads, so that part works (including hiding it again in "onmouseout") but it's displayed below everything (like in the HTML code). It seems like setting `imgbox.style.left` and `imgbox.style.top` doesn't do anything. If I set "margin" instead, the image is displayed 200px to the right and 200px down from where it originally was (but still below everything else).

What did I miss? How do I move the "imgbox" at runtime with regular Javascript (no JQuery please!)?

```js
function onHoverIn(url) {
    var imgbox = document.getElementById("imgbox");
    imgbox.style.visibility='visible';

    var newimg = document.createElement("img");
    newimg.src = url;

    var oldimg = document.getElementById("i");

    /*if(oldimg.addEventListener){ //Removed so the snippet'll run
        oldimg.addEventListener('mouseout',onHoverOut,false);
    } else {
        oldimg.attachEvent('onmouseout',onHoverOut);
    }*/
    imgbox.innerHTML='';
    imgbox.appendChild(newimg);

    imgbox.style.left = '200px';
    imgbox.style.top = '200px';
    //imgbox.style.marginLeft = '200px';
    //imgbox.style.marginTop = '200px';
}
```

```css
#imgbox {
    position : absolute;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    background : #FFFFFF; 
    filter: Alpha(Opacity=100);
    visibility : hidden;
    z-index : 50;
    overflow : hidden;
}
```

```html
<img id="i" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/53/02/a4/5302a4c318139bf5753c433b1f4c6aa8.jpg" alt="DP" onmouseover="onHoverIn('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b2/1b/07/b21b0738ea390fc56a4d3efe76ab88de.jpg')"> 
<p>Long Teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeext<br><br><br><br><br>END TEEEEEEEEEEEXT</p>
<div id="imgbox"></div>
```

Sorry, the images are pretty big, so not sure how well it'll work. I tested the code with Firefox 85.0, Chrome 88, IE and Edge by simply double-clicking the .html file and the positioning doesn't work properly in any of them.

Comment: could you please try to add your code including `onHoverOut` function as a snippet here?

Comment: I just added a snippet.

Comment: @TolgahanAlbayrak Any suggestion why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

This was quite a bit harder than I thought it would be, made some changes to your code. Hope this still works for you.

**NOTE:** I implemented an `onHoverOut` locally and noticed that when I moved my mouse around on the image it would flicker. This happens because the new image is loaded and once moving again the old image registers a `onHoverOut` (because you hover on top of the new image) which would then remove the new image, at which point the old image registers the `onmouseover` again and adds the new image. This would keep looping for as long a you move the mouse around.

```js
function onHoverIn(url) {
    var imgbox = document.getElementById("imgbox");
    imgbox.style.visibility='visible';

    var newimg = document.createElement("img");
    newimg.src = url;

    var oldimg = document.getElementById("i");

    if(oldimg.addEventListener){
        oldimg.addEventListener('mouseout',onHoverOut,false);
    } else {
        oldimg.attachEvent('onmouseout',onHoverOut);
    } 
    //imgbox.innerHTML='';
    imgbox.appendChild(newimg);
}
function onHoverOut() {
    console.log('onHoverOut: not implemented');
}
```

```css
.article{
    width:640px;
    padding:0 16px;
}
.image-box{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:0;
    /* 16:9 */
    padding-top:56.25%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.image-box img{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="article">
    <p>content before..</p>
    <div id="imgbox" class="image-box">
        <img id="i" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/53/02/a4/5302a4c318139bf5753c433b1f4c6aa8.jpg" alt="DP" onmouseover="onHoverIn('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b2/1b/07/b21b0738ea390fc56a4d3efe76ab88de.jpg')"> 
    </div>
    <p>content after..</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't use an absolute position with the "oldimage" because there are a lot more elements in my full code. This example was created to test the problem and see if it also doesn't work (which it doesn't).. I did try adding `top:0;left:0;` to the imgbox but that didn't change anything.

Comment: I figured that would be the case, will modify my answer in a bit. In the meanwhile look at @caramba's answer to get a better understanding of how positioning works.

Comment: I'm aware of the differences between relative and absolute positioning and I picked the latter for the imgbox because that's what is needed to position it freely.

Comment: I just ran your code snippet and only the upper half of the old image is loaded, like you're limiting the size to what the new image is going to be. Why 56.25% padding and only 640px width? Not every image is 16:9 and it should display the whole image for both the thumbnail and the popup, so that's not what I'm looking for. You also need `imgbox.innerHTML='';` to reset the HTML of the imgbox before you add a new image, maybe that's what's causing the flickering? There's no flickering with my code and `onHoverIn` and `onHoverOut` also only trigger once, even when I keep moving the mouse inside.